# How to sort rows in a specific order as it's own block of rows

Tags: sort

I want to sort the following rows of text to a particular order.  The `sort` commands I am using is dropping the space and bundling all the lines together without the space separation and putting them in alphabetical order.  Each block has 8 rows of line data each.

> session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT
>   cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   loginName:jack
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>   sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:04:10.899Z
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   totalJSHeapSize:42358792
>   usedJSHeapSize:36482584
>
> session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHJE
>   cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   loginName:jack
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>   sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:16:41.558Z
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   totalJSHeapSize:177754040
>   usedJSHeapSize:44842320
>
> memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   totalJSHeapSize:45252608
>   usedJSHeapSize:24555080
>   session:cabSessionID:055S75T4QC8JYC4Q0456
>   cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   loginName:frank
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>   sessionStartTime:2018-10-23T19:11:11.871Z

I want the end result to be like this:

> loginName:jack
>   cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>   sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:04:10.899Z
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   totalJSHeapSize:42358792
>   usedJSHeapSize:36482584
>
> loginName:jack
>   cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHJE
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>   sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:16:41.558Z
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   totalJSHeapSize:177754040
>   usedJSHeapSize:44842320
>
> loginName:fred
>   cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   session:cabSessionID:055S75T4QC8JYC4Q0456
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>   sessionStartTime:2018-10-23T19:11:11.871Z
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   totalJSHeapSize:45252608
>   usedJSHeapSize:24555080

Comment: Hi Jeff, each block needs to be sort in the following order: loginName, cabLoginID, session, userAgent, sessionStartTime, memoryInfo, totalJSHeapSize, usedJSHeapSize.  I don't need to reorder the blocks itself, it can stay in the same order as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to hard-code the "sorting", have awk compile the data for each block in an associative array, then print that array out in the order you want:

## scriptfile.awk

```
BEGIN {
  FS=":"
}

/./ {
  values[$1]=$0
}

/^$/ {
  print values["loginName"]
  print values["cabLoginID"]
  print values["session"]
  print values["userAgent"]
  print values["sessionStartTime"]
  print values["memoryInfo"]
  print values["totalJSHeapSize"]
  print values["usedJSHeapSize"]
  print ""
  delete values
}

END {
  print values["loginName"]
  print values["cabLoginID"]
  print values["session"]
  print values["userAgent"]
  print values["sessionStartTime"]
  print values["memoryInfo"]
  print values["totalJSHeapSize"]
  print values["usedJSHeapSize"]
}
```

Then run:

```
awk -f scriptfile.awk < input
```

As an alternative, if you don't care what order the block lines are in, but do want them still to be consistently ordered, and you have GNU awk,

## gnuscript.awk

```
BEGIN {
  FS=":"
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc";
}

/./ {
  values[$1]=$0
}

/^$/ {
  asort(values)
  for (element in values)
    print values[element]
  print ""
  delete values
}

END {
  asort(values)
  for (element in values)
    print values[element]
}
```

The above script prints the lines of each block in alphabetical order:

```
cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
loginName:jack
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT
sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:04:10.899Z
totalJSHeapSize:42358792
usedJSHeapSize:36482584
userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
...
```

Comment: would it be an easier "one liner" if the requirement of sorting it a particular way is not required?  As long as the sorting is in the same order again and again.  Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: Will this awk script work with the times?  The times contain colons.  I don't think the entire time will be captured.

Comment: it broke on lines that had more than one semicolon.  For example on session, it displays as session:cabSessionID instead of session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT

Comment: Ah, thanks, don! I was just about to update the post, but you beat me to it.  Much simpler, too -- thank you!  I'll work on a further simplification regarding Kam's direction of printing block-lines in the same order.

Comment: @Kam, I've added a GNU awk variation that's simpler, by relying on GNU awk's ability to sort; here I've chosen "ascending string", but you can also define your own sort function.

Comment: You guys rock, i tried the new script and that works as advertised!  Much appreciated on all the help.

Comment: Is there a way to sort based on "sessionStartTime" for each block using gnuscript.awk that was provided?

Comment: I think that should be a new question, since it's changing the scope from sorting lines *within* a block to sorting the blocks themselves; am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yup, you are right Jeff.  I will post it into a new question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a block of lines the same way over and over, I do not think there is a simple one-liner for that.

Since I'm concerned with the awk not catching all of the strings because of the colons in the times, I wrote up this quick little shell script.  This actually sorts them by blocks.  The order you have it in the blocks is determined by the printf.  Update that to meet your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr

(
  while read l; do
    if [[ "" == "${l}" ]]; then
      printf "loginName:%s~cabLoginID:%s~session:%s~userAgent:%s~sessionStartTime:%s~memoryInfo:%s~totalJSHeapSize:%s~usedJSHeapSize:%s~\n" ${arr[loginName]} ${arr[cabLoginID]} ${arr[session]} ${arr[userAgent]} ${arr[sessionStartTime]} ${arr[memoryInfo]} ${arr[totalJSHeapSize]} ${arr[usedJSHeapSize]}
      unset arr
      declare -A arr
      continue
    fi
    k=${l%%:*}
    v=${l#*:}
    arr[${k}]=${v}
  done
  printf "loginName:%s~cabLoginID:%s~session:%s~userAgent:%s~sessionStartTime:%s~memoryInfo:%s~totalJSHeapSize:%s~usedJSHeapSize:%s~\n" ${arr[loginName]} ${arr[cabLoginID]} ${arr[session]} ${arr[userAgent]} ${arr[sessionStartTime]} ${arr[memoryInfo]} ${arr[totalJSHeapSize]} ${arr[usedJSHeapSize]}
) | sort | tr '~' '\n'

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks Lewis for coming back.  I took your code and saved it on a file called scriptfile2 with a .sh extension.  For me to initiate the codes against the file that has this information, is it as easy as:  ./scriptfile2.sh < FinalResult.txt

Comment: If FinalResult.txt is the file containing your data, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Perl in paragraph mode, with a custom sort order defined using a hash e.g.

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -ne '
our %rank; 
BEGIN {
  %rank = (
    loginName => 1,
    cabLoginID => 2,
    session => 3,
    userAgent => 4,
    sessionStartTime => 5,
    memoryInfo => 6,
    totalJSHeapSize => 7,
    usedJSHeapSize => 8
  );
}

%h = ();
map { ($k,$v) = split(/:/, $_, 2); $h{$k} = $v } @F;
for $k (sort { $rank{$a} <=> $rank{$b} } keys %h) { print "$k:$h{$k}\n" };
print "\n";
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk '
BEGIN   {for (n=split("loginName cabLoginID session userAgent sessionStartTime memoryInfo totalJSHeapSize usedJSHeapSize", T); n; n--) FLSQ[T[n]] = n
        }

        {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {n = split ($i, T, ":")
                                 OUT[FLSQ[T[1]]] = $i
                                }
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = OUT[i]
         split ("", OUT)
        }
1
' RS="" ORS="\n\n" FS="\n" OFS="\n"  file
loginName:jack
cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT
userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:04:10.899Z
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
totalJSHeapSize:42358792
usedJSHeapSize:36482584

.
.
.
```

In the `BEGIN` section, it defines the field sequence in each record's output by assigning each field label an ascending number. When operating on multiline records, having split the label into the `T` array, it fills the `OUT` array   with the entire field, indexed by the label's number. Last action before printing the record is to rebuild the entire $0 (= record). All field and record separators have to be adapted to the multiline record layout.